# spring boot thymleaf i am trying to use conditional if in tymeleaf and tie it to a controller class to return true or false no pojo needed

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

i have a nav bar that i am using as a template.. see pic[image]

if i am on any of the tabs then i want home to show.  But if i am on the home page i don't want Home tab to show its redundant.  i cant seem to figure out how to write the thymleaf code..

i have something like this the first line is what i am interested in fixing...  can you please help with the controller part also i am sure i can do a model.addAttribute line in each method call and set the isActive to true except the home method i can set the isActive to false ... thank you

li th:text="${isActive} ?   'Home   : "

```
<li th:text="${isActive} ?   '<a th:href="@{/}">Home</a>   : "            </li>
        <li><a th:href="@{/about}">About</a></li>
        <li class="auctions"><a href="#">Auctions&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#bus4sale">Current Auctions</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>


            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a th:href="@{/contact}">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a th:href="@{/locations}">Locations</a></li>
```

Comment: For the Thymeleaf part, use [`th:if`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless) - something like this: `<li th:if="${isActive} == true"><a th:href="@{/}">Home</a></li>`.

Comment: For the controller, you need to edit your question and show the relevant part of your code - but typically I would expect you to need something like this: `model.addAttribute("isActive", Boolean.TRUE` - if it's the home page, and `Boolean.FALSE` otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this in controller:

```
model.addAttribute("isActive",true);
```

and use this in html code:

```
<li th:if="${isActive == null || !isActive}"><a th:href="@{/}">Home</a></li>
```

read more about **[Conditionals in Thymeleaf](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-conditionals)** and [simple conditionals if and unless](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless)